# How can I use Lyapunov Control for nonlinear system $\dot x = f (x, u) $

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, optimal-control, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

Recently I made my system identification algorithm SINDY to work. Not it can estimate a nonlinear model from measurement data that comes from a very nonlinear hydraulic system. The input signal increase with 1 step atvyhe time. At the top of the plot, the output signal won't increase so much compared to the beginning.

[image]

https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Mataveid

Now I have this model

$$\dot y = f (y, u) = 0.719906 + 2.533281y - 1.175728y^2 - 0.218748u^2 + 0.813850yu - 4.212704\sqrt y + 1.255115\sqrt u 
 $$

I wonder how I can find a control law with lyapunov function for this nonlinear model.

Comment: It is hard to say without an expression for $f.$ Do you have a restricted class of $f$ you are concerned about? A standard way is to use the standard Lyapunov choice $V(x(t)) = x(t)^\top x(t)$ and see that $\dot{V}(x(t)) = f(x(t),u(t))^\top x(t).$ Then see if you can choose $u$ so that the vector $f(x(t), u(t))$ has a negative dot product with $x(t)$ for any $x(t)$ you are concerned with.

Comment: @Rollen Hi. I have included the model that describes the plot. Thank you for your reply.